# How to align a column right-adjusted

Tags: mysql, sql, select, format, tabular

I want to align a column in my table. In this case 'Title'

```
mysql> SELECT Titel, KuenstlerName from Bild;
+--------------------------+---------------+
| Title                    |         Artist|
+--------------------------+---------------+
| Drei Musikanten          | Picasso       |
| Buveuse assoupie         | Picasso       |
| Die Flöte des Pan        | Picasso       |
| Paolo als Harlekin       | Picasso       |
| Die Umarmung             | Picasso       |
| Sitzende Frau            | Picasso       |
| Sternennacht             | van Gogh      |
| Der Park                 | Klingt        |
| Liegender Hund im Schnee | Marc          |
| Hauptweg und Nebenwege   | Klee          |
| Jungfrau im Baum         | Klee          |
| Das gelbe Haus           | Klee          |
+--------------------------+---------------+
```

Is it possible to align the left column to the right, like this:

```
+--------------------------+---------------+
| Title                    | Artist        |
+--------------------------+---------------+
|           Drei Musikanten| Picasso       |
|          Buveuse assoupie| Picasso       |
|         Die Flöte des Pan| Picasso       |
+--------------------------+---------------+
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: sql is a database. It handles data, it is not for handling the display of it. Yes, you can pad your string as seen below, but that changes the data (adds spaces) and not it's display. It also will only work in fixed-font scenarios.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your `Title` length is 150 then query like this

```
 SELECT LPAD(Titel,150,' ') as Titel , KuenstlerName from Bild;
```

Check [**Manual**](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-lpad-function.php) for `LPAD` function.

Comment: Don't worry for that you accepted is more important for other user for future reference.

Answer (score 4):

If `Titel` is 100 characters, then do this

```
SELECT
    LPAD(Titel, 100, ' '),
    ...
```

or

```
SELECT
    RIGHT(CONCAT(REPEAT(' ', 100), Titel), 100),
    ...
```

Comment: The second option worked for SQL on iSeries DB2. My need wasn't for right adjusting the field, but rather an input variable going into a query. Worked Wonderfully.  Allowed the optimizer to use the correct index.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the task like this:

```
SELECT LPAD(Titel,(SELECT MAX(LENGTH(Titel)) FROM Bild),' ') AS Titel, CONCAT(Kuenstler.Vorname,' ',Kuenstler.Name) AS Kuenstler 
FROM Kuenstler 
INNER JOIN Bild ON Bild.Kuenstler = Kuenstler.KID;
```